# sleep in c# does not work properly

Tags: c#, sleep

the codes below shows that sleep(1) will sleep an average of 2 miliseconds!

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
int i = 0;
long max = -1;
while (true)
{
    Stopwatch st=new Stopwatch();
    st.Restart();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    long el = st.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    max = Math.Max(el, max);
    i++;

    double time = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalMilliseconds;
    if (time >= 1000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Time =" + time);
        Console.WriteLine("i =" + i);
        Console.WriteLine("max ="+max);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        i = 0;
        dt = DateTime.Now;
        max = -1;
    }
}
```

Typical Output:

```
Time =1000.1553
i =495
max =5
```

could some body explain me the reason? and how can i fix this problem?!

Comment: `Sleep(1)` doesn't mean sleep 1 ms. It means thread will not be scheduled for execution for atleast next 1 ms. It is minimum time to be in sleeping state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting 2 milliseconds is fairly unusual, most anybody that runs your code will get 15 instead.  It is rather machine dependent and mostly depends on what other programs you've got running on your machine.  One way to change it, for example, is to start Chrome and you'll see (close to) 1 msec sleeps.

You should display more digits to avoid rounding artifacts.  A simplification of the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
    while (true) {
        st.Restart();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        st.Stop();
        Console.Write("{0} ", st.Elapsed.Ticks / 10000.0);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

Which produces on my machine:

```
16.2074 15.6224 15.6291 15.5313 15.6242 15.6176 15.6152 15.6279 15.6194 15.6128
15.6236 15.6236 15.6134 15.6158 15.6085 15.6261 15.6297 15.6128 15.6261 15.6218
15.6176 15.6055 15.6218 15.6224 15.6212 15.6134 15.6128 15.5928 15.6375 15.6279
15.6146 15.6254 15.6248 15.6091 15.6188 15.4679 15.6019 15.6212 15.6164 15.614 
15.7504 15.6085 15.55 15.6248 15.6152 15.6248 15.6242 15.6158 15.6188 15.6206 ...
```

This is normal output, I have no programs running on my machine that mess with the operating system.  This will be the way it works on most machines.

Some background on what's going on.  When you call Thread.Sleep() with a value larger than 0 then you voluntarily give up the processor and your thread goes into a wait state.  It will resume when the operating system's thread scheduler runs and enough time has expired.

What's key about that sentence is "when the thread scheduler runs".  It runs at distinct times in Windows, driven by the clock interrupt that wakes up the processor from the HALT state.  This starts in the kernel, one primary task of the clock interrupt is that it increments the clock value.  The one that's used by, for example, DateTime.Now and Environment.TickCount

The clock does not have infinite resolution, it only changes when the clock interrupt occurs.  By default on all modern Windows versions, that clock interrupt occurs 64 times per second.  Which makes the clock accuracy 1 / 64 = 15.625 milliseconds.  You can clearly see this value back in the output of the program on my machine.

So what happened on your machine is that a program changed the clock interrupt rate.  That is a rather unfortunate inheritance from Windows 3.1, the first Windows version that supported multi-media timers.  Timers that can tick at a high rate to support programs that need to do things with media, like animating a GIF file, tune the frame rate of a video player, keep the audio card fed with sound without stutter or excessive latency.  Programs like Chrome.

They do this by calling [timeBeginPeriod()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm/timeBeginPeriod.html).  They usually go whole-hog and pick the smallest allowable value, 1 millisecond.  Apparently 2 msec on your machine.  You can do this too, you'll see the Sleep(1) call now taking about 1 msec instead of 2.  Don't forget to call timeEndPeriod() when you no longer need the high rate.

But do keep in mind that this is pretty unfriendly thing to do.  Waking up the processor this often is very detrimental to battery life, always an issue on portable machines.  Which explains what mystified this site's founding father in his blog post ["Why does Windows have terrible battery life"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/10/why-does-windows-have-terrible-battery-life.html).  It doesn't, Chrome has terrible battery life :)  If you want to find out what program messed with the clock then you can run `powercfg -energy` from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

I dont think it's weird to see this result. The  Stopwatch itself probably takes a millisecond. I highly doubt you can expect a precise 1 millisecond. There is always overhead involved and I doubt sleep guarantees you that the sleep time is that precise.

Personally I would expect a range from 1-5 milliseconds.

Comment: interesting why this has gotten a -1 as I certainly agree that 1 millisecond precision is well beyond the expectation for these classes ...

Comment: "The Stopwatch itself probably takes a millisecond." How slow is your PC? I can create > 10K additional StopWatches before 1 ms is registered on the first.

Answer (score 3):

Thread.Sleep is designed to pause a thread for *at least* the number of milliseconds you specify. It basically leaves the execution of the current thead and it's up to the scheduler of the operating system to wake it again. The thing is, you cannot be sure that the underlying OS's scheduler will allow the thread to resume immediately.

I think, System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait is what you are looking for.